# Unable to increment array elements correctly for "Minesweeper"

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python, I just started with a simple example. The question was to count mines near each place in a table. Consider input file below:

```
4 4 
*... 
.... 
.*.. 
.... 
3 5 
**... 
..... 
.*... 
0 0
```

The output should be like

```
Field #1:
*100
2210
1*10
1110
Field #2:
**100
33200
1*100
```

And my code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pprint

fin = open("1.2.in")
fout = open("1.2.out")

while True:
    i, j = [int(x) for x in fin.readline().split()]
    if(i == 0):
        break
    arr = []
    for k in range(0,i):
        line = fin.readline();
        arr.append(list(line))


    pprint.pprint(arr)
    resarr = [[0]*j]*i

    for row in range(0,i):
        for col in range(0,j):
            for rowIndex in range(-1,2):
                for colIndex in range(-1,2):


#                   print row,rowIndex, col,colIndex
                    if (row + rowIndex < i) and (row + rowIndex >= 0) and ( col + colIndex < j) and (col+colIndex >=0) and (rowIndex != 0 or colIndex != 0):
                        #pprint.pprint(resarr[row][col])
                        #if arr[row+rowIndex][col+colIndex] == "*":

                        #print row,rowIndex, col,colIndex, "              ", arr[row+rowIndex][col+colIndex] 
                        #print resarr[row][col]
                        resarr[row][col] += 1  
                        #pprint.pprint(resarr)
    #                   print col+colIndex
    print i,j
    pprint.pprint(resarr)
```

I don't know what's wrong, but when I want to increment `resarr`, a total column is incremented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is

```
resarr = [[0]*j]*i
```

This means: Take `i` references to the *same* list defined by `[0]*j` and create a list of those.

The thing you want is:

```
resarr = [[0]*j for _ in range(i)]
```

This creates a new list (`[0, 0, ...]`) `i` times instead.

See this:

```
>>> a = [0] * 4
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> b = [a] * 4
>>> b
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> id(b[0])     # get the "address" of b[0]
42848200
>>> id(b[1])     # b[1] is the same object!
42848200
>>> b[0][0] = 1
>>> b
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: nice, i was gonna add an IDLE session example but ya beat me to it

Comment: I was playing with this for two hours!